# MaximizeSum - determining the maximum possible total of points

Tags: c#, optimization, solver, maximize

> The results are good, but the program is written inefficiently - it is not possible to sum even 100 items.
>
> Does anybody have an idea how to improve this?

> when the vector / group of numbers of the variable "sequence" is too large, the program takes a long time, the goal is to make it count quickly

example

```
 public interface ISolver<T>
    {
        Task<T> SolveAsync(IEnumerable<T> sequence);
    }

    public class Solver : ISolver<short>
    {
        private async Task<short> MaximizeSumAsync(IEnumerable<short> sequence, short tripleSum = 0)
        {
            if (sequence.Count() == 3)
                return (short)(sequence.Sum(x => x) + tripleSum);
            var tasks = new List<Task<short>>();
            for (short i = 1; i < sequence.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                // better option?
                tasks.Add(MaximizeSumAsync(sequence.RemoveAt(i), (short)(tripleSum + sequence.Sum((short)(i - 1), (short)(i + 1)))));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll<short>(tasks);
            return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).Max();
        }
        public async Task<short> SolveAsync(IEnumerable<short> sequence)
        {
            return await MaximizeSumAsync(sequence);
        }

        public static short Sum(this IEnumerable<short> sequence, short startIndex, short endIndex)
        {
            if (startIndex < 0)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            if (endIndex >= sequence.Count())
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            short res = 0;

            for (short i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
                res += sequence.ElementAt(i);

            return res;
        }
        public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, short index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index > sequence.Count() - 1)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Index {index} is larger than the number of elements in sequence ({sequence.Count()}).");

            if (index == 0)
                return sequence.Skip(1);

            if (index == sequence.Count() - 1)
                return sequence.Take(sequence.Count() - 1);

            var part1 = sequence.Take(index);
            var part2 = sequence.Skip(index + 1);

            return part1.Concat(part2);
        }
```

> maybe some alternative for linq?

Comment: _Maybe_ better suited for CodeReview, since this seems to be more of a "code improvement" than a "coding problem" question?

Comment: Could you also tell us what this is even trying to do? This does not make much sense to me, right now.

Comment: Hi Gqrsw. As it is currently presented, the question puts too much mental stress to the reader. Please tell us what is the goal of this program, that gives good results although it's written inefficiently. Why shouldn't have to guess what the goal is, by reading the code. Also the title of the question is intended as a summary, not as a part of the question. If the question doesn't make sense without reading the title, then the title should be repeated inside the question.